# EventHub Golang client error: amqp:internal-error

Tags: azure, go, azure-eventhub

I try to use EventHub Go client to send a simple "hello world" event but got this error message:

> *Error{Condition: amqp:internal-error, Description: The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 TrackingId:be0c66437a1447b7accdc113c84955dd_G5, SystemTracker:gateway5, Timestamp:2021-07-10T21:28:48, Info: map[]}

The code is exactly the same as this sample code here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go

The SO thread I found which somehow has similar error message is here [Getting "amqp:internal-error" when peeking messages from Azure Service Bus Queue using AMQP, rhea and Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831383/getting-amqpinternal-error-when-peeking-messages-from-azure-service-bus-queue), but it is for Service Bus and Node client.

Any idea why this issue occured?

Answer (score 2):

This error is pretty non-descriptive.
One way to trigger is to specify an EventHubs connection string without an `EntityPath=<event hub name>` in it.

So if you're using a broker level connection string you'll need to specify the EventHub you're attempting to connect to by adding `EntityPath=eventHubName`. The readme snippet does list this, but the error is admittedly not great in that situation.

I've filed this issue to at least improve the error message in that case, as it doesn't really lead you to what's wrong.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-go/issues/222